# How to run another instance of an application by double clicking on its application icon

Tags: macos

How can I run another instance of the application  while the application is already running, by clicking on the application icon in `/Applications/`?

I don't want to run it from `/Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`

Can I link a script file containing statements

```
open -n /Applications/myapp.app
```

or

```
open -n /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
```

… with the application icon click?

I've tried making changes in `Info.plist` of the application

```
key-Executable file    value-myapp
```

(present at `/Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`)

changes

```
key-Executable file   value-launch.sh
```

(present at `/Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/launch.sh`)

As I know an  Application Bundle on OS X can only be started once. By simply copying the bundle the same application can be launched twice.

Is there any solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a solution I can see is to create an AppleScript app that calls `open -n` and to use that instead. You could move the original application to somewhere other than /Applications, replace it with your new script and, if you wanted to, [change the icon](http://iconfactory.com/help/help_mac.html).

You can create such an app with `osacompile -e 'do shell script "open -n /Path/To/Application.app"' -o /Path/To/New/Script.app`.

Comment: Thanks for making me believe that it is possible.
How can i link the apple script with the application Icon(Info.plist)
I could move the original application to somewhere other than /Applications, replace it with your new script
I can create such an app with osacompile -e 'do shell script "open -n /Path/To/Application.app"' -o /Path/To/New/Script.app

The Requirement is like i want to run another instance by double clicking on the same application Icon present at /Applications/

Comment: To make your script have the same icon as the application, follow [these instructions](http://iconfactory.com/help/help_mac.html) with the original application and your script.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution requires 2+ icons for each such app in the menu bar: One for the launcher, and one per running instance.

Comment: It is fine with changing the icon of the script, It is also fine the script will help in runninig multiple instances open -n /Applications/myapp.app                                                             I want to make it working with the application bundle(eg myapp.app)